# Error when trying to link to patient profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting an error when trying to link_to a patient profile when a provider views his patients list. I have no problem displaying all the names of the patients that belong to the provider but when trying to link to the patient profile I get an undefined method 'id'.

So the way it works is, patients can search for providers and add them to the `List` model. On the provider side, I just list out all the patients that added that specific provider. Here is my erb code below,

```
<div class="body">
            <div class="body">
            <% if @active_patients.count > 0 %>
                <table>
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Patient Name</th>
                      <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <% @active_patients.each do |list| %>
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                            <%= list.patient.role.user.first_name %> <%= list.patient.role.user.last_name %>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%= link_to patient_path(id: @patient.id), class: "btn" do %>View<% end %> . #### THIS IS THE LINE
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    <% end %>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
            <% else %>
                <div class="no-records">
                    <%= image_tag "icon-no-records", class: "image" %>
                    <div class="text">You have no patients.</div>
                </div><!--no-records-->
            <% end %>
        </div><!--body-->
    </div>
```

Here is my `List` model,

```
class List < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :membershipable, :polymorphic => true
    belongs_to :provider  

    def patient
      membershipable_type=='Patient' ? membershipable : nil
    end

    def provider_user
        patient.try(:user)
    end
end
```

Also here's the error message ->

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let Rails do the work of building the path. Each ActiveRecord model has a `to_param` method  which decides how the instance will be encoded in an URL. By default it returns the model id but it could also be a slug based on the title or another property of the model.

Calling your helper like `patient_path(patient)` should do the trick.

Additionally, in your current code, you're referring to the previously unused `@patient` variable, even though it looks like you want to refer to `list.patient` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
<% @active_patients.each do |list| %>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <%= list.patient.role.user.first_name %> <%= list.patient.role.user.last_name %>
    </td>
    <td>
      <%= link_to patient_path(id: @patient.id), class: "btn" do %>View<% end %> . #### THIS IS THE LINE
    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

you have the variable `list` available to you. It appears that you get the `patient` by doing `list.patient`, as you do here:

```
<%= list.patient.role.user.first_name %> <%= list.patient.role.user.last_name %>
```

But, then you try to use a variable called `@patient`, here:

```
<%= link_to patient_path(id: @patient.id), class: "btn" do %>View<% end %> .
```

when you don't have the variable `@patient`. So, you get your `nil` error.

Instead, it seems you should do:

```
<%= link_to patient_path(id: list.patient.id), class: "btn" do %>View<% end %> .
```

Or, as milgner points out, you could simply do:

```
<%= link_to patient_path(list.patient), class: "btn" do %>View<% end %> .
```

Also, you might want to look into the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter), which you violate (IMO) when you do:

```
list.patient.role.user.first_name
```